# php include outputs two double quotes

Tags: php, include

I used php include to retrieve my site template and its working but it shows two double qoutes before outputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'load.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Common.php. (it has same result if I just include common.php so I don't paste my load.php here)

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up global vars and included files. */
define('INC', 'includes/');
define('FUNCS', 'functions/');
define('CLS', 'classes/');
define('MODS', 'modules/');
#paths

#Initialing
// include require files to set initial
require_once(ABSPATH . 'configs.php');
function openDB() {
    global $dbCon;

    require_once(ABSPATH . CLS . '/class-db.php' );

    if (isset($dbCon))
        return;

    $dbCon = new db(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
}
openDB();
?>
```

Even if common.php were empty, still quotes are there :/

and output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
" <!-- this double quote should not be here -->
" <!-- this double quote should not be here -->
<div>hello world!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so I have a blank space on every pages. does include file send any header like this?

Comment: can you add content of common.php and load.php to your question?

Comment: Could you post the content of the common.php & the load.php files

Comment: updated my question. i tested empty common.php and still quotes were there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some non-ascii character before or after `<?php` tag in one of included files (not necessary common.php and load.php may be also configs.php or class-db.php), which is unseen in your editor but visible in browser. You may examine your files with HEX editor to check this or play with "ob_get_clean" to find the exact point where those symbols appear.

Comment: I tested `include 'empty.php';` and there was no extra symbols but when I saved empty.php with `Encoded UTF-8` those symbols appeared.

Comment: Well , just searched for `*.php` in my root and saved them all with `UTF-8 Without BOM` Encode. should i delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

Eugene is right. 
 I was facing the same issue and while googling came to this thread but did not understood it right.

Then searched a little more with different keywords like "php include adding spaces and line breaks" and found another thread after which I understood the meaning of this thread.

Also this isn't a php problem really, it mostly happens when we copy and paste code between different editors and somehow the extra invisible hex data is added because the document type is changed between utf-8 and ansi etc.

Here's the url which makes it more correct, found the solution at the end of the page - 
[php-require-include-adds-line-break-to-html](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10365446-php-require-include-adds-line-break-to-html)

Hope it help.

Comment: in my case that was because of some files were `Encoded ANSI` while saving and other files were another encoding format `UTF-8` (I'm using notepad++)
so I encoded all files with `UTF-8 Without BOM` and saved all and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "common.php / load.php" in notepad++ and change the encoding to "encod in UTF-8 without BOM"

Answer (score 0):

add

`<div style='clear:both;'></div>`

before

```
<?php
require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'load.php';
?>
```

> it will be still show up but doesn't effect on your layout